# How to get Url Port for Rails instance without request/response loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to get the url/port that the current rails app is
running on without using the http request/response loop?

Or a way to invoke a request to self from within a rails app that will
spawn the correct request object to get the url/port?

Answer (score 1):

`env["SERVER_PORT"]`

Would using this environment variable work?

Comment: that sounds promising. do you know when this is set? meaning at what point in the startup process is it available and not nil?

Comment: Works great, if `request` is around.